# How to change the characters order in a string in python 3.X?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, random, replace

let's say for example that I got 100 random words (not even real words just words)...
like "ABCD" and I want to make a program that takes a word like the one I mentioned and prints you all the options of this word in random order.
for example the word "ABC" will print: "ABC", "BAC", CAB", "BCA", "CBA".
I could do it manually but if I have 100 words I can't...
so how do I write a code that does it in python?

Comment: It sounds like you want `itertools.permutations`. Do you want every possible way to order the letters? If so then for your example you missed "ACB".

Comment: yes, i lost the acb

Comment: Step 1: Create the permutations. Step 2: Shuffle them.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using itertools:

```
import itertools
import random

words = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3']

for word in words:
    permutations_list = [''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(word)]
    random.shuffle(permutations_list)
    print(permutations_list)
```

Comment: thank you guys really appreciate it!